# Creating a middleware for redirect auth in Angular: Component, Resolver or Guard?

Tags: angular

I am working on implementing an external auth system in my Angular application, and I want to ensure that I am following the best approach.

The auth system works in the way that by a given redirect `URL` if the authentication goes well, it will redirect the user with a token in query params in my case to a component I've created called `AuthComponent`, then that token has to be used to get authenticated via another service, if this authentication will go well, then the user will be able to navigate in the angular application, else had to be redirected to `/error` component.

What I've tried is to do all that logic inside the component, but I don't really need the component to be loaded, so I was looking for a better approach to do it, maybe by using a resolver or a guard.

Here is how the component looks like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.scss']
})
export class AuthComponent {
  router = inject(Router)
  route = inject(ActivatedRoute)
  authService = inject(AuthService)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const token = params['token'];
      if (token) {
        this.authService.authenticate(token).pipe(
          map(response => {
            if (response && response.status === 200) {
              this.router.navigate(['/']); // Authentication successful
            } else {
              this.router.navigate(['/error']); // Authentication failed
            }
          })
        );
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/error']); // No token found
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  helper = inject(JwtHelperService)
  http = inject(HttpClient)

  authenticate(token: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`/api/auth/gab-auth/`, { params: { token: token }, observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        if (response.ok && response.body) {
          let accessToken = response.body['access_token'];
          if (accessToken) {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken);
          }
        }
      })
    );
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    return token != null && !this.helper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
}
```

Then I have a guard that allows or not the user to reach the pages based on `isAuthenticated` value.

Comment: You certainly don't need component to check authentification state. `canMatch` guard function can do the job - verify token in service and proceed with route or redirect to login page bye returning Observable `true` or redirect url respectively. Read the fine manual https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis so I can just create a route without the component but only with canMatch param in it?

Comment: No, every route must have component and/or children.. How can your app exist without components? Usually authorization check must be added to all root routes unless their are public (i.e. /login) because any valid route can act as entry point to your app.

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis What i mean is that for the auth route, I can just use a canMatch guard without a component but only with a redirectTo the base URL `HomeComponent`, and in the guard just allow the redirect if the authentication goes well or else navigate to the `ErrorComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I have solved it by using a guard instead of a component?

First of all, I've gotten rid of the AuthComponent but I still keep the route for it by replacing the `component` with an empty `child` (this allows to use the guard without any component, else with a `redirectTo` is executed before the guard).

My `app-routing` for the auth now looks like this:

```
  {
    path: 'auth', canActivate: [tokenGuard], children: []
  }
```

While the `tokenGuard`:

```
export const tokenGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, _state): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> => {
  const router = inject(Router)
  const auth = inject(AuthService)

  const token = route.params['token'];

  if (!token) {
    return of(router.parseUrl('/error')); // No token found
  }

  auth.authenticate(token).pipe(
    map(response => {
      if (response && response.status === 200) {
        return router.parseUrl('/'); // Authentication successful
      } else {
        return router.parseUrl('/error'); // Authentication failed
      }
    })
  );

  return of(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add guard to protected root routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadComponent: () => import('./login/login.component').then(m => m.LoginComponent),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppContainerComponent,
    canActivate: [isLoggedIn],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'jobs',
        canMatch: [isModuleAllowed],
        loadChildren: () => import('./jobs/jobs-routes'),
      },
       {
        path: '',
        component: MainMenuComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
  },
];
```

And login guard:

```
export const isLoggedIn: CanActivateFn = (): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> => {
  const router = inject(Router);
  return inject(LoginService).isLogin().pipe(
    map(logged => logged || router.parseUrl('/login')),
  );
};
```

Login service checks login state against api and caches the state (implementation is out of question scope).

Comment: While can you make an example of isModuleAllowed?

Comment: `isLoggedIn` is checking for login all routes (by exception of 'login') whereas `isModuleAllowed` additionally checks some route to get permission for certain path. It just returns `true | false`.
The main point is that you don't need special route for authorization like '/auth'. Just define routes for your app normally and add guards to protected ones.